# void pointer arithmetic in qsort

Tags: c++, c

i m trying to make something like qsort but i always get error when i try to use with `void*`

```
void my_sort(void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int(*compare)(const void*, const void*))
{
    size_t i, j;
    const void *first, *second;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num*size; i+=size)
    {
        for (size_t j = size +i; j < num*size; j +=size)
        {
            first = base + i;
            second = base + j;
            if (compare(first,second)<0)
            {
                swap(base,i,j);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C or C++? You shouldn't be writing anything like this in C++.

Comment: You get an error when you use void pointer where? What is the error? what language are you using? Please put more details next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first = ((char*) base) + i;
second = ((char*)base) + j;
```